# How do I say "In another news" so it would make sense to a native speaker in an email?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-request, formal

Let's say after an intro paragraph I want to start another paragraph with an unrelated news subject in my life (but it is a formal email) and I want to say "**In another news**" and I suspect "**Entre altre notizie**" would not make sense, so how would I say it properly? Or is there a common phrase with a similar meaning (even google.it is not being helpful)?

Question number 2: Does "**Cari colleghi**" in the beginning of the email also make sense to a native speaker?
Grazie mille!

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: http://context.reverso.net/traduzione/inglese-italiano/in+other+news
This could be usefull

Comment: Indeed, “reverso context” is very useful, if one prefers a computer-generated array of randomly chosen translations, rather than understanding what means what.

Comment: Passando ad altro, is a good one, see some examples here [examples passando ad altro from Italian to English](https://idiommaster.com/search/it-en?search-term=passando%20ad%20altro).

Comment: @AntonioMatarrese: A parte che questo è più un commento alla risposta esistente che una vera risposta, il link è a un sito generato automaticamente con spezzoni di traduzioni la cui affidabilità non è chiara, come per il già menzionato “reverso context”.

Comment: _In another news_ is not good English; you might say **On another topic** or **in other news**, though the latter may be thought of as a somewhat joking allusion to how news programmes and papers are organised.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately ***Entre altre notizie*** has no meaning in Italian. If you mean ***In other news*** you could translate it with ***cambiando argomento*** or ***passando ad altro***.

The expression ***cari colleghi*** is fine at the beginning of a letter, corresponding to "dear colleagues".